# How do I change iPad's default email sort order?

Tags: ipad, email

I'm using the mail app on my iPad.
When I open the app the mails are shown in date order, but not starting with newest mail. Sometimes it starts with mails from months ago, sometimes it starts with yesterday or even today, but it's not newest mail I've received.

How can I change the sort order to that puts the most recent email is at the top?